# How to merge hasMany relationships and return a relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to merge 2 collections, because I need to search for records in multiple columns, `team_one_id` and `team_two_id` depending on if its an away game or home game.

This happens in function `matches` when trying to merge them. When I call `merge` on the first relationship, function `matches` doesn't return an actual relationship, but returns a collection.

Exception:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `matches` where `matches`.`team_one_id` = 1 and `matches`.`team_one_id` is not null and `winning_team_id` = 1) union (select * from `matches` where `matches`.`team_two_id` = 1 and `matches`.`team_two_id` is not null))
```

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $table = 'teams';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function homeMatches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match', 'team_one_id');
     }

     public function awayMatches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match', 'team_two_id');
     }

     public function matches() {
        return $this->homeMatches()->union($this->awayMatches()->toBase());
     }
}
```

Comment: Did some searching for you, don't see any way of doing this with Eloquent.  Relationships aren't designed to match one or the other field, they are designed to have one foreign key.  There's no reason why you can't design a method to run a query to return the matches though.  Any reason why you haven't opted for that instead of focusing on matches being a relationship?

Comment: I havent opted for that as if I did something like `return Match::where('team_one_id', $this->id)->orWhere('team_two_id', $this->id)->get();` I wouldn't be able to query on it after calling it, unless I removed `->get()` and just called get on every instance, or am I doing this all wrong? It seems I can't call things like `orderBy` on it unless I remove the `->get()` on the return.

Comment: Yes, that's true, because get() runs the query and returns a collection so it's no longer queryable.

Comment: I guess I'm just being OCD about the constantly calling `get()` part. I'll opt for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent Relationships aren't designed to match one or the other field, they are designed to have one foreign key.  You can run a query within your method to get the results you need without relying a relationship.

As discussed in the comments, if you want to re-use that query, contain that logic in a protected function.

```
 protected function allMatchesQuery()
 {
     // This needs to be wrapped in a nested query or else your orWhere will not be contained in parentheses.
     return Match::where(function($q) { 
          $q->where('team_one_id', $this->id)->orWhere('team_two_id', $this->id);
     });
 }

 public function getMatches() {
    return $this->allMatchesQuery()->get();
 }


 public function getRecentMatches() {
    return $this->allMatchesQuery()->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
 public function matches() {
    return $this->getRelationValue('homeMatches')->union($this->getRelationValue('awayMatches')->toBase());
 }
```

Because of homeMatches() function return a Relation instance but the dynamic property returns a Collection.

Comment: This throws `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getBindings does not exist.`, so I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: What happened when you change the **"homeMatches"** and **"awayMatches"** to **getRelationValue('homeMatches')** and **getRelationValue('awayMatches')**

Comment: I think this reply solving your problem. Because I tested it on a example laravel project at the moment. Your exception message about of dynamic property so I change this reply to getRelationValue()